# Django: override save method on ModelForm that inherits values from another ModelForm

Tags: python, django

For convention at my company any validation must be done in the form and not in the view of any Django APP.

I've this code that applies to my form, as a regular form. But I've "upgraded" it to be a 'ModelForm' and this code, works but doesn't save the "document" attribute on the 'Nana'.

1.- What am I doing wrong?
2.- What benefits are of doing the validation in the 'form' vs 'view'?

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db import transaction
from nucleo.models.documento import Documento
from nucleo.models.nana import Nana
from nucleo.models.tipo_documento import TipoDocumento



class NanaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Nana
        fields = ['nombre', 'apellido_paterno', 'apellido_materno', 'fecha_de_nacimiento', 'direccion',
                  'telefono_o_celular',
                  'genero', 'foto', 'latitud', 'longitud']


    def clean(self):
        form_data = self.cleaned_data
        try:
            tipo_documento = TipoDocumento.objects.get(form_data['tipo_documento'])
            if not tipo_documento.validar_documento(form_data['documento']):
                self._errors["documento"] = ["El documento no cumple el formato."]
                del form_data['documento']
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self._errors["tipo_documento"] = ["No existe el tipo de documento seleccionado."]
            del form_data['tipo_documento']
        return form_data

    @transaction.atomic()
    def save(self):
        valid_data = self.cleaned_data
        documento_codigo = valid_data.pop('documento')
        documento_tipo_id = valid_data.pop('tipo_documento')
        documento = Documento(codigo=documento_codigo, tipo_documento_id=documento_tipo_id)
        documento.save()
        nana = Nana(documento=documento, **valid_data)
        nana.save()
        return nana


class DocumentoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Documento
        fields = ['tipo_documento', 'codigo']
```

**models.py**

```
class TipoDocumento(models.Model):
    nombre_corto = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=25)
    nombre_largo = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100)
    tipo_patron = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, choices=TIPO_PATRON)
    tipo_contribuyente = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, choices=TIPO_CONTRIBUYENTE)
    tipo_longitud = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, choices=TIPO_LONGITUD)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_corto



class Documento(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.codigo

    tipo_documento = models.ForeignKey(TipoDocumento, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=25)



class Nana(Usuario):
    # secretaria_registradora = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
    habilidades = models.ForeignKey(Habilidad, blank=True, null=True)
    especialidades = models.ForeignKey(Especialidad, blank=True, null=True)
    experiencia_con_mascotas = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='nanas_fotos',
                            default='media/nana-default.png')
    # antecedentes_policiales = models.FileField(upload_to='nanas_antecedentes_policiales')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Usuario(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    nombre = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(blank=True, null=False, max_length=100)
    fecha_de_nacimiento = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    documento = models.OneToOneField(Documento, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True, validators=[validar_documento])
    telefono_o_celular = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    esta_activo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    genero = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, choices=GENERO, max_length=1, default='f')
    direccion = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=160, default='')
    latitud = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=60, default='')
    longitud = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=60, default='')
```

**views.py**

```
class RegistroView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        nana_form = NanaForm()
        documento_form = DocumentoForm()
        context = {'nana_form': nana_form, 'documento_form': documento_form}
        return render(request, 'app_administrador/crear-registro-como-secretaria.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        nana_form = NanaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if nana_form.is_valid():
            nana_form.save()
        else:
            print(nana_form.errors)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

This is what I had in the **view.py** before (when the save process was done in this file):

```
class RegistroView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        nana_form = NanaForm()
        documento_form = DocumentoForm()
        context = {'nana_form': nana_form, 'documento_form': documento_form}
        return render(request, 'app_administrador/crear-registro-como-secretaria.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        nana_form = NanaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        documento_form = DocumentoForm(request.POST)

        if all((nana_form.is_valid(), documento_form.is_valid())):
            documento = documento_form.save()
            nana = nana_form.save(commit=False) #Don't save it to the DB. Just store the variable for now.
            nana.documento = documento #adding documento to 'Nana' model through NanaForm.
            nana.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: You didn't add field **tipo_documento** in your filed list of forms.py file.

Comment: I get this error: 'django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (tipo_documento) specified for Nana'.